# PyQt file dialog opening before main window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have made a UI in QT designer and converted it with PySide. I am now trying to attach some code to one of the buttons in the design. I am trying to create a file dialog when the toolbutton is pressed, but I am having issues with the file dialog opening before the main window and then the toolbutton not doing anything.
This is the code I have, minus some formatting lines:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.Filepathselector_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Filepathselector_2)
        self.toolButton_2 = QtGui.QToolButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.toolButton_2)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.Filepathselector_2.clear)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), showDialog(self))
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.Filepathselector_2.setToolTip(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Select file", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.toolButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "...", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


def showDialog(self):

        fname, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(MainWindow, 'Open file', "", 'MP3 Files (*.mp3)')
        print fname
        print _

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am using two variables for the file selection as PySide has a bug with returning a tuple instead of a string here. The code runs the GUI fine, but opens the file dialog before the GUI is loaded, and then when I try to use the toolbutton nothing happens. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), showDialog(self))
```

Specifically, `showDialog(self)` is calling `showDialog` and passing its return value as the slot to connect. In this case you could make `showDialog` a method, so `self` is passed implicitly, and connect it like this:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.showDialog)
```

You could also use a lambda, like so:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda: showDialog(self))
```

The lambda method is more generally applicable (e.g. you could pass something other than `self` for the argument).

Answer (score 2):

You're executing the function call in your connect statement with `showDialog(self)`, so change the line

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), showDialog(self))
```

to

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.toolButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.showDialog)
```

and indent the function `showDialog` so that it is inside your class. This means you don't have to pass it the `self` parameter at all.

That fixed it for me.